# WebSocket - c# .NET

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, websocket

Não achei quase nada sobre WebSockets + .NET no google, gostaria de saber como é feito esse servidor utilizando o .NET futuramente a ideia é criar um aplicativo e um hardware (Arduino) que faça comunicação com esse servidor WebSocket.
É possível criar um servidor WebSocket em ConsoleAplication ou ServiceWindows? ou somente em asp.net (pagina web)? como é criado esse servidor? em JavaScript? ou tem como faze-lo utilizando o C# mesmo? eu pesquisei bastante, mas ainda está um pouco vago a lógica do WebSocket, se alguém puder compartilhar um código simples só pra entender mesmo como funciona o WebSocket agradeceria muito!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30524243/4713574

Comment: Mas neste caso ele é um cliente, eu quero ser o host

Comment: Para ser o  host basta criar a conexão WebSocket e acessar pelo mesmo  endereço que vc está utilizando para acessar seu site, apenas alterando o  tipo de acesso http por ws ou wss(caso seja conexão segura) não há necessidade de fazer configurações no  host as portas são liberadas de acordo com  o que vc define no seu source c#

Answer (score 2):

Você poderá rodar o servidor no console se usar asp net core (inclusive no linux). 
O ideal é escrever utilizando o signalr ([módulo npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aspnet/signalr-client)) para facilitar a sua vida, permitindo implementar o web socket sem ter muito conhecimento.
Para rodar o servidor no console basta rodar o comando dotnet run na pasta do projeto ou dando o play no visual studio usando a opção console, não lembro o nome mas você verá duas, uma usando IIS Express e a outra o console.
Para saber mais sobre o signalr acesse o tutorial (em inglês) https://dotnetthoughts.net/getting-started-with-signalr-using-aspnet-core/

Answer (score 1):

O SignalR par amim hoje é a melhor solução dem websocket c#.

Acho que vale estudar um pouco sobre ele.

Utilizo em algumas aplicações minhas, é muito simples de fazer e gerenciar as conexões.

Você pode escolher se conectar a todos usuarios, um usuario ou grupo de usuario.

Esse tutorial do Eduardo Pires me ajudou muito: http://www.eduardopires.net.br/2013/04/aspnet-signalr-introducao-e-utilizacao/

Answer (score 0):

Sim é possível criar um websocket utilizando console application. Ele é criado utilizando C# mesmo e você pode encontrar um código de exemplo neste artigo na [documentação oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets).

Neste link da MDN tem um tutorial ["Escrevendo um servidor WebSocket em C #"](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_server)